# How do use both `grep` and `which` on a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, grepl

I have one search that uses `which`, and another search that uses `grep` as follows:

```
dates <- myframe[grepl(abreviation,myframe$geo),"date"]
dates <- c(dates, myframe[which(myframe$geo == fullname),"date"])
```

`abreviation` and `fullname` are are two different strings.

I tried using `|` which returned 0 entries. I also tried `endsWith`, but this returned the warning that only the top result was going to be used, and the list only had one result.

The issue I'm having with this is that it's not returning a date in a string format, which is what `date` is, but instead a number integers.

What do I need to do differently to get a vector of these dates

Edit: Here is a sample dataset-

pastebin.com/yXq6khNV

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a sample of your data.frame myframe.  [This SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) has advice about well structured questions.

Comment: @kaliczp That was an error, `myframe2` == `myframe`

Comment: It looks like your `which` call is probably redundant. You should be able to subset appropriately with just the `==` call. That would also allow you to use `|` more easily.

Comment: @rosscova Unfortunately "abreviation" is not a subset of "fullname"

Comment: It shouldn't need to be. `grepl(abreviation,myframe$geo) | myframe$geo == fullname` should work as a subset condition.

Comment: @rosscova gave you the solution: `dates <- myframe[myframe$geo == fullname | grepl(abreviation,myframe$geo), "date"]` should work.

Comment: Here is a data sample http://pastebin.com/yXq6khNV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by passing the already filtered data frame to `grepl`:

```
dates <- myframe[grepl(abreviation,myframe[which(myframe$geo == fullname),]),"date"]
```

Answer (score 1):

`which` outputs an integer vector, whereas `grepl` outputs a boolean one. To  get them to match and work together, try it without the `which` call. You also need to tidy up those `NA`s in the `geo` column (I also changed your `fullname` to "New York, NY" since "New York, USA" didn't appear in your table):

```
dates <- myframe[ !is.na( myframe$geo ) & 
                      ( grepl(abbreviation,myframe$geo) | myframe$geo == fullname ), 
                  "date" ]
```

Which gives (the tibble format is because I used `readr` to read in your dataset):

```
> dates
# A tibble: 1 × 1
               date
              <chr>
1 12/30/10 02:37 PM
```

If you're losing the format along the way for some reason, you could specify it, although it's not in `Date` format, so I'll just specify `character` here:

```
dates <- myframe[ !is.na( myframe$geo ) & 
                      ( grepl(abbreviation,myframe$geo) | myframe$geo == fullname ), 
                  as.character( "date" ) ]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried that, it seems to be returning the entirety of the data set, whereas when I try the two separately, I get a much smaller number.

Comment: Can you include the `abbreviation` and `fullname` objects? Preferably using `dput` instead of linking externally.

Comment: They're generated based on the input, but the sample I've been using is `abbreviation = ", NY"` and `fullname = "New York, USA"`, so abbreviation is looking based on the city, and the second is the state.

Comment: How do you read in this dataset? R silently convert characters to factor. Maybe it is the reason why was the result integer. If you raw data in the file `sample.csv` read it without enabling conversion. E.g. `myframe <- read.table("sample.csv", sep=";", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactor = FALSE)`

Comment: I think your problem is that your `geo` column has some `NA` values, so `grepl` returns NAs there.

Comment: @kaliczp I have a function that casts the date and groups by year, and it keeps failing because of the output of these two lines unfortunately. I think I'm taking too much of a C based approach, and that somehow I should be concatenating data frames a different way.